# When to use Task in Interface Methods in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

There are **interface methods that you obviously know that will be `async`**, implementations that will read from the disk for example, you can easily decide to use `Task`. There are also **interface methods that might use `async`**, you can make them return `Task` too.

I can't help but see `Task` as an implementation detail that I'm hesitant to put `Task` on my interfaces when I'm not sure if the implementation will be `async` / will use `async` methods. If I decide to not use `Task`, the implementation methods can't be `async` when needed.

Although it feels weird to adjust the contract based on the requirement of the implementation, this is what I will do. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Part of the contract *is* "a result will be available straight away" vs "a result might take some time to appear". It's annoying that you need to make that distinction at the point that you define the contract, but it's unavoidable unfortunately. Whether the method uses `await` is an implementation detail (and isn't exposed in the interface), but the fact that it returns `T` vs `Task<T>` is part of the contract.

Comment: `Task` is *not* an implementation detail. Whether the method uses `async` for the implementation is, but not that it returns a promise of work to be done in the future.

Comment: why not to make method in Interface `async` and when not needed just put `await Task.CompletedTask;` and continue with `sync` code ?

Comment: @demo You can't make interface methods `async` -- `async` is an implementation detail. It's a lot cheaper to make the method non-async, then `return Task.CompletedTask;` or `return Task.FromResult(...)`

Comment: @demo I believe the op is aware of the possibility. The question is, rather, if the task-based nature of the result should be part of the interface signature or not (i.e. an implementation detail or part of the contract).

Comment: @canton7 I didn't know `Task.CompletedTask` and `Task.FromResult(...)` exist.

Comment: @canton7, yeah, my mistake... I mean not `async` but method that returns `Task`

Comment: Not only you have to choose between `T` and `Task<T>` when designing an interface, but between `Task<T>` and [`ValueTask<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1) as well. Here is an interesting video with a discussion about the later option: [Understanding how to use Task and ValueTask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fj-LVS8hqIE).

Comment: It's worth noting that the [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=netcore-3.0#remarks) in the documentation says, "Only if performance analysis proves it worthwhile should a ValueTask<TResult> be used instead of a Task<TResult>."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this the correct way?

Yes. Just use `Task` if you know there will sometimes be opportunity to be asynchronous.

That still leaves you the opportunity to not, because the interface cannot require the use of `async` - it can only require the return type of `Task` or `Task<T>`.

If you end up not needing to do anything asynchronously, you can use [`Task.FromResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult) to return a completed `Task` with a value. For example:

```
protected override Task<int> SomeMethod() {
    return Task.FromResult(1);
}
```

Or [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask) if there is no return value.

Otherwise, if you don't specify `Task` as the return type, and you want to do something asynchronously, you're left with two options:

1. Use synchronous methods in your implementation,
2. If no synchronous methods are available for what you want to do (which is increasingly common), then you either have to:

   - Block synchronously on the asynchronous methods, or
   - Use `async void` (if the method returns `void`), which can cause other complications.

All of those are worse options than returning a completed `Task` in cases where you don't need to run asynchronously.

Comment: @dpp [Blocking on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) can, yes, that's why it's a bad idea. If you just use `Task` in the interface, then no one will feel forced into that.